"Error：encoding overruns Uint8Array" when sending transactions?
I tried to compile 2 swaps into one transaction and got this error,
Error：encoding overruns Uint8Array

I know there is a 1232 limit for a single transaction, my question is, is there any way to reduce my instructions size? or is there any other way can make my code works?
const transactionMessage = new TransactionMessage({
        payerKey: payer.publicKey,
        recentBlockhash: blockhash,
        instructions: innerInstructions, // lots of instructions
    })
    const itemV = new VersionedTransaction(transactionMessage.compileToV0Message())
    itemV.sign([...innerSigners, payer]);

Here is code I use. thanx

The 1232 limit is fixed, the only way you can get around that is to make your transaction smaller. One way to achieve this is using Address Lookup Tables. If this isn't enough/isn't applicable to your case you have no choice but to split your instructions up across multiple transactions.
I'm guessing the reason you want all instructions in one tx is to have it be executed together. This can still be achieved with multiple transactions using transaction bundles. Solana doesn't natively support this, but Jito does. Check out this reference implementation.
